# Perl: grep from multiple arrays at once

Tags: arrays, perl, blank-line

I have multiple arrays (~32). I want to remove all blank elements from them. How can it be done in a short way (may be via one foreach loop or 1-2 command lines)?

I tried the below, but it's not working:

```
    my @refreshArrayList=("@list1", "@list2", "@list3","@list4", "@list5", "@list6" , "@list7");
    foreach my $i (@refreshArrayList) {
        $i = grep (!/^\s*$/, $i);
    }
```

Let's say, @list1 = ("abc","def",**""**,"ghi"); @list2 = ("qwe",**""**,"rty","uy", "iop"), and similarly for other arrays. Now, I want to remove all blank elements from all the arrays.

Desired Output shall be: @list1 = ("abc","def","ghi"); @list2 = ("qwe","rty","uy", "iop")  ### All blank elements are removed from all the arrays.

How can it be done?

Comment: `@$_ = grep /\S/, @$_  for @AoA;`

Comment: @zdim, Would you please explain?

Comment: Then I'd better post it properly, so bear with me for a minute...

Comment: Your attempt doesn't work because  `"@ary"` (under quotes!) interpolates that array into a string of array elements separated by spaces -- so `("@list1", "@list2",...)` is simply an array of strings, `("a1 b1...", "a2 b2...",...)` and that regex always finds something other than spaces in each of them (as long as an array has at least one element!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a list of list references and then iterator over these, like

```
for my $list (\@list1, \@list2, \@list3) {
     @$list = grep (!/^\s*$/, @$list);
}
```

Of course, you could create this list of list references also dynamically, i.e.

```
my @list_of_lists;
push @list_of_lists, \@list1;
push @list_of_lists, \@list2;
...
for my $list (@list_of_lists) {
     @$list = grep (!/^\s*$/, @$list);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@$_ = grep /\S/, @$_  for @AoA;   # @AoA = (\@ary1, \@ary2, ...)
```

Explanation

- First, this uses the [statement modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers), "inverting" the usual `for` loop syntax into the form `STMT for LIST`

  > The `for(each)` modifier is an iterator: it executes the statement once for each item in the LIST (with `$_` aliased to each item in turn).

  It is mostly equivalent to a "normal" `for` loop, with the notable difference being that no scope is set and so there is no need to tear it down either, adding a small measure of efficiency.<sup>†</sup> Ae can have only one statement; but then again, that can be a `do` block.  Having no scope means that we cannot declare lexical variables for the statement (unless a `do` block is used).

  So the statement is `@$_ = grep /\S/, @$_`, executed for each element of the list.
- In a `for(each)` loop, the variable that is set to each element in turn as the list is iterated over ("topicalizer") is an alias to those elements. So changing it changes elements.  From [perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops)

  > If VAR is omitted, `$_` is set to each value.
  >
  > If any element of LIST is an lvalue, you can modify it by modifying VAR inside the loop.

  In our case `$_` is always an array reference, and then the underlying array is rewritten by dereferencing it (`@$_`) and assigning to that the output list of `grep`, which consists only of elements that have at least one non-space character (`/\S/`).

---

<sup>†</sup>  I ran a three-way benchmark, of the statement-modifier loop against a "normal" loop with and without a topical variable.

For adding 100e6 numbers I get 8-11% speedup (on both a desktop and a server) and with a more involved calculation (`$r = ($r + $_ ) / sqrt($_)`) it's 4-5%.

A side observation: In both cases the full `for` loop without a variable (using default `$_` for the topicalizer) is 1-2% faster than the one with a lexical topical variable set.